# self.tableView reloadData doesn't work in UISplitViewController master detail application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, tableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I was trying to update tableview in masterviewcontroller from detailviewcontroller using delegate. I called reloadData from delegate methods but it didn't wwork. I still couldn't solve this.

this is my delegate method in MasterViewController

```
- (void)updateScore:(DetailViewController *)controller withScore:(NSUInteger)score {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_selectedIndexPath];

        NSLog(@"%@", cell.detailTextLabel.text);

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Best score: %lu", (unsigned long)score];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

        NSLog(@"%@", cell.detailTextLabel.text);

}
```

from NSLog the cell.detailTextLabel.text was updated, but the tableview doesn't reload

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that your view controller is the tableview delegate and the datasource

If you are using storyboards, under connections inspector, your tableview needs your view controller set as dataSource and delegate

if you want to just do it in your viewcontroller.m file in the viewDidLoad method you can use these lines

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: thanks for the response,

but I've already done that. because I need data source and delegate methods from masterview to show data details on detailviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //other init 
    }

   if(_selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row && _selectedIndexPath.section == indexPath.section){
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Best score: %lu", (unsigned long)score];
    }

}
```

Your can try move code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` above then tableView reloadData

Answer (score 0):

1. `[self.tableView reloadData]` updates all visible cells in the table. It calls `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and so on. In other words: It completely renews the table.
2. The only correct way to set cell content is to set it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The code:

   ```
   if (cell == nil) { cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; //other init}
   ```

   never gets called since iOS 6 if you use storyboards.

So with your code you:

1. use an incorrect way to setup cell content.
2. clear all your settings with `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

Solution:

1. Save `score` in `__strong ivar` or `property`.
2. Call `[self.tableView reloadData]`. It calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` at appropriate times.
3. Setup a new `score` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Suggestion: Use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){ [self.tableView reloadData]; });
```

to return fast from the delegate and not wait until the table was updated.